# Add menu entry to WinForm application MainMenu

Tags: winforms, drop-down-menu, menu

I require a menu entry to be added to a help menu of any Windows Form Application.

In the same sense as WinRAR adds menu options to a rightclick in Windows Explorer, same concept in every Windows Form Application in the help menu.

Is there a global template I can access/modify to add a addition option to a help menu?

**UPDATE**

A help context menu from VS 2015 - Example of what I need, but for any Windows Form Application using a Menu like this in image.

[Programmatically add a extra option to any windows for applicaiton using a menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWhji.png)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. I take it you mean you want to add your own option to the Windows shell right click menu? I take it you're not simply talking about a menu strip in your own program?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is even possible, I've certainly never seen any other application do this. I'm afraid this is beyond my area of expertise. Hopefully someone else can help with the new information you provided.